# Firebase Hosting deploy with Google Cloud Build throwing "No such file or directory" error

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I built a simple ReactJs app and tried using **Google Cloud Build** to deploy it as soon as I push a new commit to the master branch on Github.
For that I added an "On push to master" trigger and followed every step from [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase) to configure my Google Cloud and Local Project. In the end I created a **cloudbuild.yaml** file with the following content:

[image: cloudbuild.yaml content]

After a new commit and push the cloud build logs a correct `npm install` and `npm run build`, but the firebase stops at the following step.

[image: Cloud Build Error Log]

I didn't understand which file/directory is missing, nor how to fix it. Could anyone help me a little?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a whole day of work I found out the problem. Apparently when you generate the firebase image mentioned in the tutorial all its files need to use End of line LF, but in windows it sets all of them to CRLF. I solved the problem using the WSL terminal in windows.

Comment: This is a lifesaver! Thanks a ton. The weirdest issue I have ever seen. One of the generic solutions for all software related problems should be "Don't Use Windows"!!

Comment: Another option is to git clone with --config core.autocrlf=false